# "Fixing" broken JSON with unescaped quotes

Tags: python, json

This code is supposed to fix JSON structures that are broken by having unescaped quotes in strings and try to recover if possible.

The code can only recover on certain cases and can be fooled by certain combinations, but that's to be expected. It's not trying to handle all possible cases, which is impossible anyway. The `nesting_stack` is not used fully (only the last item), but could be useful to do even more restrictive checks (ex. to know that when you exit an object if you are now in another object or array).

Don't consider this as something that should be used in production but rather a programming exercise :-)

Any comments are welcome

```
import json
import re
import unittest
from json import JSONDecodeError
from typing import Any

expected_characters_by_prestring_value = {
    "[": (",", "]"),
    "]": ("[", ","),
    "{": (":",),
    "}": (",", "{", "]"),
    ":": (",", "}"),
    ",": (":", "{", "}", "[", "]"),
}


def fix_unescaped_quotes(raw: str) -> str:
    in_string = False
    output = ""
    nesting_stack = []
    for index, character in enumerate(raw):
        if character == '"' and raw[index - 1] != "\\":
            if in_string:
                first_nonwhite_character_ahead = re.search(
                    r"\S", raw[index + 1 :]
                ).group()
                if (
                    first_nonwhite_character_ahead
                    in expected_characters_by_prestring_value[nesting_stack[-1]]
                ):
                    in_string = False
                else:
                    output += "\\"
            else:
                in_string = True
        else:
            if not in_string:
                if character.strip() != "":
                    nesting_stack.append(character)
        output += character
    return output



def parse_and_fix(raw: str) -> Any:
    try:
        return json.loads(raw)
    except JSONDecodeError:
        return json.loads(fix_unescaped_quotes(raw=raw))


class JsonFixUnescapedQuotesTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_completely_invalid(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            parse_and_fix("invalid_json")

    def test_valid(self):
        self.assertEqual({}, parse_and_fix("{}"))

    def test_invalid_single_array(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            ['he said "hello world" and left'],
            parse_and_fix("""["he said "hello world" and left"]"""),
        )

    def test_escaped(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            ['he said "hello world" and left'],
            parse_and_fix("""["he said \\"hello world\\" and left"]"""),
        )

    def test_escaped_mix(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            ['he said "hello world" and left'],
            parse_and_fix("""["he said \\"hello world" and left"]"""),
        )

    def test_invalid_object(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            {"key": 'value " with quote in the middle'},
            parse_and_fix("""{"key": "value " with quote in the middle"}"""),
        )

    def test_invalid_2_item_array(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            ['invalid " string', "valid string"],
            parse_and_fix("""["invalid " string", "valid string"]"""),
        )

    def test_wont_get_fooled_by_colon(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            ['invalid ": string', "valid string"],
            parse_and_fix("""["invalid ": string", "valid string"]"""),
        )

    def test_wont_get_fooled_by_colon_after_object(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            {"key": 'value":'},
            parse_and_fix("""{"key": "value":"}"""),
        )

    def test_wont_get_fooled_by_comma_in_key(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            {'key",': "value"},
            parse_and_fix("""{"key",": "value"}"""),
        )

    def test_valid_mini_sample(self):
        parse_and_fix("""{"explanation": " ""}""")
```

Comment: Does it work? This forum is for reviewing working code and your first sentence suggests that might not be the case. If it's working, might want to change it up to 'it is doing this thing' instead of 'it should do this thing'. Also, a specific question is often more answered than 'any comments are welcome', it's unclear what you want.

Comment: You are right, I didn't post the latest version. Now everything should pass. Thanks for noticing :) It "works" as long as tests are passing, althought "work" is a little fuzzy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This review sticks closely to your current implementation and test suite because I'm not
certain I understand which types of JSON quoting errors you aim to fix and
which types you are willing to ignore.

**Needlessly long var names don't help**. If taken to extremes like
`first_nonwhite_character_ahead` and `expected_characters_by_prestring_value`,
they make the code harder to read and edit. Rather than trying to create names
that are fully explicit on their own (an impossible goal in programming), you
are much better off trying to create *names that are clear in context*. A
variable, function, or class name never lives in isolation; it inherits a
context from the surrounding code, comments, and project. If that context is
appropriate, shorter names can be equally clear and much easier to manage. One
way to approach such matters is to be attentive to naming conventions that your
code and comments can establish to provide consistency and clarity. In the
illustration below, I take advantage of some general programming conventions
(for example, an iteration index can be just `i` rather than `index`, because
nearly every programmer in the world is familiar with this sort of naming) and
I establish some of my own conventions (for example, `nw` in variables that
deal with non-whitespace).

**Named constants can help readability**. In the illustration below, notice how
the simple `QUOTE` and `BACKSLASH` constants -- plus the brief comment, "Handle
non-escaped quote" -- make the code's intent and operation immediately evident
to the reader.

**During iteration over a sequence, looking backward via index subtraction is
inherently fraught**. Consider what happens on the first character when your
code checks `raw[index - 1]`. Python won't raise an IndexError; instead, it
will check the last character of the input text -- which is not what you want.
In this case, an ordinary previous-character status variable works better.

**Dict lookup with unknown inputs need to be guarded**. We don't know in
advance what characters will be in the input text, which means that your
lookups into your dict of expected characters ahead needs to be done via
`dict.get()`.

**Compile the regex in advance so that you can search with start position**.
That eliminates the need to search over a substring.

**The nesting stack isn't a stack**. You never pop anything off of it. You
never look farther back than the most recent item. It's just another
previous-character variable.

**Use comments to support the code**. Even with thoughtful naming, code is
often too complex for quick reading. That's when comments can provide
additional guidance to the reader. In some cases, that guidance acts like signs
on the road -- very brief markers indicating what's ahead. Sign post comments are also an easy mechanism to provide some organizational structure to the code. In other cases, comments might lend support to a naming
decision or convention (for example, the comment that explains `prev_nwnq`).
And sometimes a comment explains an algorithm's purpose, strategy, or behavior
in an intuitive way (for example, the explanation for how quotes are handled
when we are already inside a quoted string -- essentially, the heart of your
algorithm).

```
EXPECTED_CHARS = {
    "[": (",", "]"),
    "]": ("[", ","),
    "{": (":",),
    "}": (",", "{", "]"),
    ":": (",", "}"),
    ",": (":", "{", "}", "[", "]"),
}

QUOTE = '"'
BACKSLASH = '\\'
NW_RGX = re.compile(r'\S')

def fix_unescaped_quotes(raw: str) -> str:
    # Setup output str and a few status-tracking variables.
    output = ''
    in_string = False
    prev = None
    prev_nwnq = None

    for i, char in enumerate(raw):
        # Handle non-escaped quote.
        if char == QUOTE and prev != BACKSLASH:
            if in_string:
                # If we're already inside of a quoted string and if the next
                # non-whitespace character is an expected one, then we have
                # exited the quoted string. Otherwise, escape the quote.
                nw_char = NW_RGX.search(raw, pos = i + 1).group()
                if nw_char in EXPECTED_CHARS.get(prev_nwnq, ''):
                    in_string = False
                else:
                    output += BACKSLASH
            else:
                in_string = True
        elif not in_string and char.strip():
            # Previous non-whitespace, non-quoted character.
            prev_nwnq = char

        # Add character to the output.
        output += char
        prev = char

    return output
```